# Select custom meta_key and meta_value from wordpress in single query

Tags: select, wordpress

I have a custom field named 'video_code' and yoast seo's custom field named '_yoast_wpseo_title', both under meta_key column like this:

```
meta_id | post_id |     meta_key       |     meta_value
 123         321        video_code           <iframe>code</iframe>
 123         321        _yoast_wpseo_title   Title of the post
```

Is it possible  to get the Title and the video_code of the post like in the example below?

```
 _yoast_wpseo_title   |    video_code
   Title of the post       <iframe>code</iframe>
```

Comment: Yes...But you don't seem to have made any effort yourself. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: I don't expect someone to write the code for me. I am currently learning sql and I just wanted advice with what statements can I use. I can't figure out how to display 2 separate columns using data from same column and don't know what statement can be used to achieve this. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: You want to use a `JOIN` on `meta_id` and `post_id`

Comment: One way is to join the table twice (with different aliases, say a and b). Then get one column from first join `a.meta_value` and the other from the 2nd: `b.meta_value`.

Comment: I tried this query
`SELECT
   a.meta_value,
   b.meta_value
FROM 
    sp_postmeta AS a
         JOIN 
        sp_postmeta AS b
        ON a.meta_key =  '_yoast_wpseo_title' AND
    B.meta_key = 'dp_video_code'
      ORDER BY a.meta_key`

and I get for every title all video_codes from other titles.